# Track Time Spend on Each Website

Tags: ruby, time, web, browser-plugin

Is there a way to track how much time you spend on each website? Ideally I'd like something I could plug into my browser that would give me information that I could pass into a Ruby program. Each day it might output something like this:

```
http://www.google.com => 45.02 minutes
http://www.espn.com => 34.21 minutes
http://www.facebook.com => 26.35 minutes
```

If this doesn't exist, what would you use to build this?

Comment: I am eager to see the answer.Nice to think :)

Comment: Do you mean tracking the time you personally spend on a website or tracking the amount of time visitors to your website spend on other sites?

Comment: Also, do you mean to track the amount of time a user has the website focused and is actively interacting with it or just has it open in a tab (in which case mine would be `stackoverflow.com => 24 hours` since it is always open in one of my tabs).

Comment: @CharlesCaldwell I mean tracking the time I personally spend on a website. 

I was thinking about just tracking how long the website was open in the tab because I image that would be a lot easier to do than tracking directly interacting with the website. It would be really cool to track both if possible.

Comment: You probably have to write a browser extension that then saves/uploads the data to the file system/a server.

Comment: Searching for 'Time Tracker' on the Chrome store yields a few plugins, have you tried any of those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Firefox you could write a greasemonkey script to do this. There's also a plugin that does this for you: https://addons.mozilla.org/En-us/firefox/addon/leechblock/

Its primary purpose is to block sites that are time wasters, but it also can track the time you spend on a site or block of sites.

If you use Chrome this time tracker seems to do what you want: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/timestats/ejifodhjoeeenihgfpjijjmpomaphmah?hl=en